# Suppressing Console Logging by Azure KeyVault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm accessing an Azure key vault, using C#, in a Net Core 2 console app. Whenever the app runs, the console window gets hit with messages like this when I retrieve a secret from the vault:

> 2017-12-26T18:03:49.8610049Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: ADAL PCL.CoreCLR with assembly version
>   '3.17.3.35304', file version '3.17.41219.2324' and informational
>   version 'b6afaeae7cff965e66649e0ee7e8c29071d5a7e6' is running...
>   2017-12-26T18:03:49.8621855Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition started:
>           Authority: https://login.windows.net/[...]/
>           Resource: https://vault.azure.net
>           ClientId: [...]
>           CacheType: null
>           Authentication Target: Client
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:49.8981211Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: Loading from cache.
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:49.9010018Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   TokenCache.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:49.9060990Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   TokenCache.cs: No matching token was found in the cache
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:50.2185881Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   TokenCache.cs: Storing token in the cache...
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:50.2211369Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   TokenCache.cs: An item was stored in the cache
>
> 2017-12-26T18:03:50.2351165Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 -
>   AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs: === Token Acquisition finished
>   successfully. An access token was retuned:
>
> ```
>     Access Token Hash: [...]
>     Expiration Time: 12/26/2017 7:03:49 PM +00:00
>     User Hash: null
> ```

I don't recall doing anything in my code to set up any kind of logging for the key vault access. However, I have configured Serilog's ILogger throughout the app, so maybe that's being picked up, somehow.

How do I suppress these messages from being displayed?

Comment: Have you looked at [adding a filter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#filters)?

Comment: I'll try that if there's no more "direct" answer. I'm not sure that the messages I'm seeing in the console window are coming through Serilog, or whether they're getting there through some other mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, my C# foo is not strong after a year of writing no code.  I think all of the Microsoft supplied .NET dll's will recognize and read a config file if laid down next to them and I know there's a standard way to adjust the diagnostic outputs via the XML therein.  Don't know if that works with Serilog or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the source code of [Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/KeyVault/dataPlane/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault), but did not find any relevant logging.

> 2017-12-26T18:03:49.8610049Z: 29c98a86-9e1d-4a5d-86d6-daf8f2cfdc56 - **AcquireTokenHandlerBase**.cs: **ADAL** PCL.CoreCLR with assembly version '3.17.3.35304', file version '3.17.41219.2324' and informational version

Based on the log information, I tried to leverage [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to decompile the package [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) and found the following code:

[image]

[image]

You could disable the trace logging under ADAL library via the following code:

```
LoggerCallbackHandler.UseDefaultLogging = false;
```

**TEST:**

[image]

Comment: @Bruce_Chen, this is the most remarkable answer I've seen on stackoverflow in a long, long time. If I could award more than one star or thumbs up I'd do it. Thanx! I would >>never<< have thought to research the problem the way you did. So thanx for teaching me that, too.

Answer (score 0):

For version of **2.x** of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`, you'll need to call this:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

AdalTrace.LegacyTraceSwitch.Level = TraceLevel.Error;
```

For version **3.x+** use Bruce_Chen's answer:

`LoggerCallbackHandler.UseDefaultLogging = false;`